# Xamarin.Forms xaml become colorless and non-editable

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, color-scheme

Whenever I close a xaml file and reopen it then file become colorless and non-editable like I can write anything but unable to remove.Whole keyboard is working except tab,space,backspace. And to resolve this issue I have to reopen whole solution. Please guide me how to solve this problem. I try to reset whole setting but still facing problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by enabling "Xamarin.Forms Xaml Previewer".

Answer (score 0):

Follow these tips:

**1. First, reset your settings completely by going to Tools - Import and Export Settings - Reset all settings completely.** - I know you've done it before but it seems strange that your issue is still persisting.

[image]

**2. If the colour coding is still off, go to the settings and edit the colouring scheme by going to Options - Environment - Fonts and Colours** - This could help fix your problem relating to the colour scheming.

[image]

**3. If the issue is still persisting then uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.** - If this step does not work you need to tell us more about your problem and give us some more details if you expect an answer.

Mark this as correct if I have solved your problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I resolve the issue by enabling "Xamarin.Form xaml Previewer". Thanks for your response.